# Can Bokeh application using one Bokeh Server be deployed to serve multiple users without additional frameworks like Flask etc?

Tags: python, web-applications, bokeh

I'm trying to create an application using Bokeh, which could be deployed and serve the number of users. For example, for each user, it is supposed to download the data from the external source and create a number of plots based on it so each user could have a separate page with the plots to interact with.

I saw some examples of bokeh.embed with Flask and Tornado but I wonder if it is possible to create such app without additional frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is already the default behavior of the bokeh server. Whenever a new user requests the bokeh application a new (server) document is created, which is independent of all the other documents. See [the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications) for details.

This should work as long as you can do everything from within bokeh. If you want to do more (server other content, authenticate users, integrate with already existent website) you can embed bokeh in another webframework like flask or tornado.

Note that the bokeh server is built upon tornado, so that tornado isn't really an "additional" dependency. Embedding the bokeh server in a tornado session makes it easier to use tornado features.

Comment: Thanks! Got slightly better understanding after trying some examples